# How to query a date using strftime to format

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am trying to grab all the records for the month.  The string I have to query with is in this format `2019-01-12`.  The record I am querying for is a DateTime record so it has a format like this `2018-08-11 13:39:22.959330`.

So I am trying to structure a query that would achieve this

```
Score.where('user_id = ? AND date_closed.strftime("%Y-%m) = ?', current_user.id, date)
```

Where `date` is the `2019-01-12` string.  The above code produces the error

> FUNCTION date_closed.strftime does not exist

I did google but was unable to locate something that achieved this.  Most solutions involved searching inside a range of dates, I would really like to try to keep the search method the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `DATE_FORMAT` function for that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_closed, "%Y-%m")
```

EDIT: you'll have to also format the date you are passing to the query

Answer (score 2):

You can use mysql data functionos [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

```
Score.where('user_id = ? AND YEAR(date_closed) = ? AND MONTH(date_closed) = ?', current_user.id, date.year, date.month)
```